# special symbol for " '

Tags: php, html

I have some var containing `'`, `"`

`$var = "Hello \" World '";`

`<input type="text" value="<?=  $var ?>" >`

when browser render this code above  we will see input element containing only 'Hello'.

how solve this problem without using special symbols like `&rdquo;` in Db strings must contain `'`, `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how solve this problem without using special symbols like `&rdquo;`

You don't, although `rdquo` is the wrong character reference to use in this case.

Run text through `htmlspecialchars()` to turn it into HTML before you insert it into an HTML document.

```
<input type="text" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($var) ?>">
```

Comment: It should be noted that, when rendered to the page, the result is exactly `Hello " world '`, nothing more or less. If the form is submitted without changes, that is the exact value that the server (and therefore the database) will receive.

Answer (score 2):

[HTML Entities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) is what you need.

This is similar to htmlspecialchars but if you require all input substrings that have associated named entities to be translated, use htmlentities() instead.

Comment: If you need entities for everything that can have an entity, then you're doing UTF-8 wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Char html codes](http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp)!

> $var = "Hello \" World '";

I use html special char:

`" - special html char - &quot;`

`$var = "Hello &quot; World '";`

Result:
`Hello " World '`